# pyz内のテキストファイルにアクセスしたい

Tags: python, python3

python 3.x

`zipapp`モジュールを使って，pyzアーカイブファイルを作りました．
pyzの中にテキストファイルが含まれている場合，そのテキストファイルへどのようにアクセスすればよいのでしょう．
Javaの場合はjarファイル内のテキストを読み取れると思うのですが，Pythonでは不可能なのでしょうか．

例

```
test.pyz
|-- main.py
`-- a.txt
```

- main.py内からa.txtにアクセスしたい
- test.pyzと同じディレクトリにa.txtを置けば読み取れるが，pyzの中に入れたい

Answer (score 1):

おそらく [pkgutil](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/pkgutil.html) モジュールの get_data か、[pkg_resouces](https://docs.galaxyproject.org/en/master/lib/pkg_resources.html) モジュールの resource_stream などが使えるでしょう。

この辺の記事を参考にしてください。
[python: can executable zip files include data files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5355694/9014308)
[Way to access resource files in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10935127/9014308)
[Python: 自作パッケージにデータファイルを含める](https://blog.amedama.jp/entry/2015/12/26/012332)
[Using C based Python modules in zipped Python directories](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38624132/9014308)
[How to read a (static) file from inside a Python package?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6028000/9014308)

Comment: pkg_resourcesモジュールの関数を使うことで，アクセスすることができました．